# Which one is the best way to download video/audio from URL with specific filename?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would ike to find a solution for downloading a video/audio from a URL when I click on a HTML button.

One special point: The URL its external (so I do not have any chance to touch it) but I would like to specify the filename before the downloading starts.

I tried it over PHP, but im not sure if this method is the best/simpelst one. Because I have to define few headers, which are currently not working for a (mp4) file.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['title'], $_GET['link'])) {

    $FileName = $_GET['title'];
    $Link = $_GET['link'];
    $ContentType = get_headers($Link, 1)["Content-Type"];


    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . $FileName . '"');
    header('Content-type: ' . $ContentType . '');

    readfile($Link);

};
?>
```

Questions:

- What do I wrong? I do always receive a 0kb file.
- is there a more simple way to do it over JS or jquery?
- What if its an Audio only URL that I want to download. Can I use same headers?

Comment: What debugging have you done?

Comment: I tried with different headers, which I found on the internet. But at least, no luck. Even that, im not sure, if there is a more simpler way to do it.

Comment: For PHP you need to enable fopen_wrappers http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. **What debugging have you done?** Have you checked the value of `$Link`? What does `get_headers()` return for that URL?

Comment: @Phil ok now I see. The button which calls the PHP with the arguments, is build like that: `download.php?link=www.google.com/example&test123` But the `$Links` has the result of only `download.php?link=www.google.com/example` - but not the rest. So there is one issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've forgotten to include the protocol (ie `https://`) on those links. You'll also need to URL encode the parameter in your HTML so you don't lose any query parameters.

For example, to use `https://example.com/example?test123`, you'll want

```
href="download.php?link=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fexample%3Ftest123"
```

Producing that encoded parameter can be done via...

- [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.urlencode.php) in PHP

  ```
  <?php $link = 'https://example.com/example?test123&HERE-is-the-real-Content'; ?>
  <a href="download.php?title=Whatever&link=<?= urlencode($link) ?>">Download</a>
  ```
- [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in JavaScript

  ```
  let link = 'https://example.com/example?test123&HERE-is-the-real-Content'
  let a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = `download.php?title=Whatever&link=${encodeURIComponent(link)}`
  a.textContent = 'Download'
  ```

  or, if you're building HTML strings (not recommended)...

  ```
  const input_URL = 'https://...'
  html += `<a href="download.php?title=Whatever&link=${encodeURIComponent(input_URL)}">Download</a>`
  ```

  **Note**, I'm using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in these JS examples.

---

You should also make sure the remote URL is valid. For example

```
$headers = get_headers($Link, 1);
if (strpos($headers[0], '200 OK') === false) {
    http_response_code(404);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: thank you. But the URL includes a `&` even its encoded. So I think, I need to use urlencode() or rawurlencode(). Which one would you prefere?

Comment: @EmbaBakar I don't understand your question

Comment: What is, if you use this: `https://example.com/example?test123&HERE-is-the-real-Content`? The download.php will receive only the part of the URL until test123. The `&` will cut the argument, and the rest will not be pass to the PHP. This is the issue here.

Comment: Yes, that's why the entire `link` URL needs to be encoded. I've added it to my answer

Comment: OK now I get it. But one more quesiton, to make sure: If I encode my URL on JS before I pass it to the PHP - do I have to decode it on PHP side, before download the file like above (with the header stuff)?

Comment: @EmbaBakar no, PHP's request super-globals (ie `$_GET` and `$_POST`) are already decoded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186147/discussion-between-emba-bakar-and-phil).